# Contribute new command to variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a visual studio code extension and am trying to contribute a new action to the drop down menu associated with variables. I am writing a custom preview and so need access to the value of the variable - much like the existing "copy value" command.

[image: Variable drop down menu]

[I have found where the default menu is created in the VS-code github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f2334a79d34986f4ab5834f69a961d7249303fd0/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/browser/variablesView.ts#L168), but cannot work out how to add my own commands to this list. Can anyone suggest how I can contribute to this menu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported. The available contribution points are documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus), which only includes these two debugging-related ones:

- The debug callstack view context menu - `debug/callstack/context`
- The debug toolbar - `debug/toolbar`

It looks like there's already an open feature request for this though:

- [[Debug] Expose the contribution.menus for Variable view (#70377)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70377)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#debugcallstackcontext-menu-inline-group

> We now support contributions to the `debug/callstack/context` menu
>   `inline` group. Commands contributed to this group will be rendered
>   inline in the call stack when a user hovers over the Debug Session
>   element.

[image: debug context menu contribution]